# Prevent IDEA from inserting back quote when auto complete attributes

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

When I autocomplete an attribute in scala IntelliJ IDEA, it insert it while surrounding it with back quote ` like this :

```
`myAttribute` instead of myAttribute
```

This is annoying and I'd love to remove this behaviour. How to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

Intellij only does this if the attribute or the variable name you are using is also a keyword in scala. So that it may reference the correct one. And its the feature of scala and not intellij.
If it is happening for other cases too.. then please recheck your Intellij Scala Code style, or just RESET your intellij .

Comment: It does it every time I auto complete an attribute and that since I installed Idea. Thanks anyway.